# Npm install returns error when laravel project setup

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I created my Laravel 10 project via the Laravel installer. When it is created, I run `npm install` and get the following error:

```bash
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Vadim\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-25T14_26_52_654Z-debug-0.log
```

I have installed npm and node globally

[image]

my error log file:

[image]

I have reinstalled NPM using `npm i -g npm@next-9` but it does not help.